# Why are blobs used?

Tags: javascript, cordova, blob

Blobs are Linairy Large OBjects, but why are they used, especially in the context of JavaScript?

If you search the interwebz, you get alot of definitions of blobs, but not why they are used.

So my questions are:

- **Why**? (in which context, use cases?)

  - Especially regarding filestorage in Cordova (so by means of JavaScript)
- What is the **added value** when working with blobs.

Example:
When storing data to the filesystem (by means of JavaScript), tutorials first convert the String to a blob before its stored. But Why? You could just write the String value to a file, it doesn't need to be a blob.

Edit: An example of blob usage in Cordova can be seen [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#write-to-a-file-)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

Comment: @theaccordance I've read that, it's like I said. There is alot of information about what a blob is. But I don't find real-world cases were blobs are used, and for which purpose

Comment: You generally don't use them in JavaScript unless you're interacting with raw file data

Comment: Please check below thread for details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285857/when-is-using-mysql-blob-recommended

Comment: Please check below thread for links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285857/when-is-using-mysql-blob-recommended http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717264/should-i-use-mysql-blob-field-type http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624807/what-is-the-differences-between-blob-and-text-in-mysql-data-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the added value when working with blobs.
>
> Example: When storing data to the filesystem (by means of JavaScript),
>   tutorials first convert the String to a blob before its stored. But
>   Why? You could just write the String value to a file, it doesn't need
>   to be a blob.

A `Blob` can store `String`, `Number`, `Array`, `ArrayBuffer`, `Boolean` a single or multiple `File` objects, which inherits from `Blob`, or multiple `Blob`s.

One example advantage to using `Blob`s instead of `String` would be storing single or multiple `File` objects within a single `Blob` instead of a possibly lengthy `data URI`, or `data URI` within a `data URI`.