# why can I only use blobs on the current session

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I decided I'd look at how youtube is doing what they're doing , 
and I found it odd that I couldn't access videos directly and instead have
to go through their website to get access.

It seemed quite strange, when I noticed that youtube is using the
normal video tag. but , the problem was that it's src was something with a BLOB.
would somebody please explain to me why I can only use BLOBs in the current session, and more accurately - what is the process that is being performed
where , how and by whom?(is it the browser or the server that allow
this kind of one timed communication , or both , and if how so?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Blob URL` exists for the lifetime of the `document` which created the `Blob`; or, if `Blob.prototype.close()` is defined, until `blobInstance.close()` is called on the `Blob` instance; or `URL.revokeObjectURL()` is called on a `Blob URL` referencing an underlying `Blob` instance.

> [8.6. Lifetime of Blob URLs](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#blob)
>
> A global object which exposes `URL.[createObjectURL()][2]` must
>   maintain a **Blob URL Store** which is a list of `Blob URL`s created
>   by the `URL.createObjectURL()` method, and the [`Blob`](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dfn-Blob) resource
>   that each refers to.
>
> When this specification says to add an entry to the `Blob URL Store`
>   for a `Blob URL` and a `Blob` input, the user-agent must add the `Blob
>   URL` and a reference to the `Blob` it refers to to the `Blob URL
>   Store`.
>
> When this specification says to remove an entry from the `Blob URL
>   Store` for a given `Blob URL` or for a given `Blob`, user agents must
>   remove the `Blob URL` and the `Blob` it refers to from the `Blob URL
>   Store`. Subsequent attempts to dereference this URL must result in a
>   network error.
>
> This specification adds an additional unloading document cleanup step:
>   user agents must remove all `Blob URLs` from the `Blob URL Store`
>   within that [`document`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-document).

See also

- [Why are blobs used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36996548/why-are-blobs-used/36996841#36996841)
- [Where is Blob binary data stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38239361/where-is-blob-binary-data-stored)