# what is difference between using BLOB vs TEXT (retrieval and inserting speed) in mariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Hi Please suggest me should I will be using BLOB or TEXT.I have a requirement where i have to store large amount of text,I have read few post they all have talked about storage but not about about retrieval and inserting speed(if you are about to suggest file system storage but this not project requirement for now).One of them was telling text is faster than BLOB but no concrete proof in documentation,that led me to ask this question please if you guys can help me on the same.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7071662/14955

Comment: thilo yes clob is in waiting list https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=936

it is blob sorry i am editing that thing

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624807/what-are-the-differences-between-the-blob-and-text-datatypes-in-mysql?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: yes thilo i have read the same but no documenation proof about being faster than clob/blob neither any reason to make it logical just a statement

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer:  `TEXT` and `BLOB` will be about the same speed.

Long Answer:

- Ultimately `TEXT` and `BLOB` are just a bunch of bytes.  The main cost in inserting/fetching such columns is in finding the row and parsing it.  In some situations, the bytes are "off-record", thereby necessitation an extra disk hit (unless cached).
- There is some CPU processing difference.  But this is relatively minor.  When moving `TEXT` between the table and the client, the `CHARACTER SET` *may* be changed; this costs something.  (Not applicable to `BLOB` or any `%_bin` `COLLATION`.)
- Another CPU diff:  When `INSERTing` data, the *characters* are checked for validity.  This causes errors if you have bytes that do not match the encoding specified for the client.

Note that the differences say that `TEXT` *may* be *slightly* slower than `BLOB`.

Here's another technique...  If you have some moderately large text fields, it is actually faster than `TEXT` *or* `BLOB` to have the *client* `COMPRESS` the text, then store into a `BLOB` column.  The reason why this is likely to be faster is that fewer bytes need to be shoveled around.  And the buffer_pool cache is more effective.  (Note: I am not talking about `ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED`.)

Answer (score -1):

**BLOB** and **CLOB** data might take a long time to retrieve.

**TEXT** is a data-type for text based input.

More details: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: Why would a TEXT be faster to retrieve than a BLOB of the same size?

Comment: Because TEXT is stored as plain text(strings) which have a character set and collation where as BLOB datatype stores binary objects which is unstructured and no collation or character set. Hence TEXT will perform faster.

Comment: @MebinJoe, I'm fairly sure that isn't completely correct. TEXT and BLOB have exactly the same storage characteristics. The difference is collation as you describe. If a TEXT is retrieved on a different charset than the current connection extra CPU overhead occurs in converting this. Most of the time is however in retrieval in the storage engine. The performance of both should be compariable, but I would expect TEXT to be faster.