# How to store paragraphs in a mysql and the limit to it

Tags: mysql

Well, I am developing a website which is supposed to give information about a searched keyword, I want to store the information in the MySQL database, the information is in paragraphs and each paragraph(700-1000 words) is stored row wise  in a table which has two columns date and paragraphs, I wanted to know how many paragraphs i can store in such a table and is there a better way to achieve this purpose (i.e without storing the entire paragraph in the database)?

Comment: You can store paragraphs in a database. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071662/mysql-text-vs-blob-vs-clob and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html for more information. You may also need [full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BLOB` or `TEXT` data type will give you around 65000 bytes. Assuming you are using ASCII text, you will be able to store 65000 characters in a single row. If your paragraph is 1000 words with each word averaging 6 characters, that's 6000 characters. You will be able to store around 11 paragraphs. If you want to store more information, see `MEDIUMTEXT` or `LONGTEXT`.

To searching through so many characters you can set up [full text indexing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html).

You should definitely try out MySQL's performance with `TEXT` datatype and full text indexing. Run some load tests and review its efficiency/practicality in your application.