# mysql : update table field type to Clob

Tags: mysql, text, clob

i think that there is no type Clob in mysql.
my question is: 
is this true? and if it is true(Clob doe'sn't exist in mysql) what type can i use for saving a very long text?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071662/mysql-text-vs-blob-vs-clob

Comment: You can use `TEXT` which Holds a string with a maximum length of 65,535 characters. Or there is a LONGTEXT --> Maximum size of 4GB or 4,294,967,295 character

Comment: MySQL has a datatype TEXT or LONGTEXT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TEXT` You can use [**TEXT OR BLOB**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-data-types.htm) datatype.

```
BLOB or TEXT − A field with a maximum length of 65535 characters.
BLOBs are "Binary Large Objects" and are used to store large amounts of binary data, such as images or other types of files. 
Fields defined as TEXT also hold large amounts of data. 
The difference between the two is that the sorts and comparisons on the stored data are case sensitive on BLOBs and are not case sensitive in TEXT fields. 
You do not specify a length with BLOB or TEXT.
```